# Why is my C# camera controller script for Unity only switching between two of the cameras, and not switching back?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

Camera seems to only work between two of the cameras, and does not switch back to different cameras like it's supposed to. Probably doing something foolish as I'm brand new to this. Help much appreciated.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
```

This is Main Camera in the scene.

```
public Camera MainCamera;
```

These are the other cameras in the scene.

```
public Camera FrontCamera;
public Camera LeftCamera;
public Camera RightCamera;
public Camera BackCamera;
```

Functions

```
void Start()
{

MainCamera = Camera.main;

MainCamera.enabled = true;

FrontCamera.enabled = false;
LeftCamera.enabled = false;
RightCamera.enabled = false;
BackCamera.enabled = false;
}

void Update()
{

if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))

    if (MainCamera.enabled)
    {
        FrontCamera.enabled = true;
        MainCamera.enabled = false;
        LeftCamera.enabled = false;
        RightCamera.enabled = false;
        BackCamera.enabled = false;

    }

else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))

    if (FrontCamera.enabled)
    {

        LeftCamera.enabled = true;
        FrontCamera.enabled = false;
    }
```

Code works as expected to this point.

```
else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    { 
        if (LeftCamera.enabled)
        {

            RightCamera.enabled = true;
            LeftCamera.enabled = false;
        }
    }
else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    { 
        if (RightCamera.enabled)
        {
            BackCamera.enabled = true;
            RightCamera.enabled = false;
        }
    }
else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        if (BackCamera.enabled)
        {
            MainCamera.enabled = true;
            RightCamera.enabled = false;
        }
    }
else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))

        if (!MainCamera.enabled) ;
{
        MainCamera.enabled = true;
}
}

}
```

Comment: Hello @Tim, were you able to figure out your issue?

Comment: Just about to give it a shot actually...been so busy with school projects lately. The hitting Space only once makes a lot of sense...didn't know about switch, (CAMERA_STATE), or case commands, but seem very useful. Help appreciated, will reply if I have any further issues. Cheers.

Comment: Look up switch-case statements for C#. They're built into the language. Then, create your own state enum for your camera states. Those are some basic elements essential to object oriented programming. They are powerful tools.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for your help again. Always good to learn of something new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tabs and brackets are confusing. Also, the structure of your nested if, if else-if else-ifs are confusing. Your last statement is basically empty:

```
else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))

    if (!MainCamera.enabled) ;
{
    MainCamera.enabled = true;
}
```

Instead, set up your code structure to react to the space bar press once, then check the state of your camera system:

```
If (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
{
    switch (CAMERA_STATE)
    {
        case MAIN:
            MainCamera.enabled = false;
            FrontCamera.enabled = true;
            break;
        case FRONT:
            FrontCamera.enabled = false;
            LeftCamera.enabled = true;
            break;
        case LEFT:
            LeftCamera.enabled = false;
            RightCamera.enabled = true;
            break;
        case RIGHT:
            RightCamera.enabled = false;
            BackCamera.enabled = true;
            break;
        case BACK:
            BackCamera.enabled = false;
            MainCamera.enabled = true;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```